# Storybook in Salesforce Lightning or alternative

Tags: salesforce, storybook, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

Recently I've joined a new job and they are working with Salesforce. They have all pages with APEX and I propose to migrate to Lightning components.

I've created the first 7 components and I'm using Atomic Design Methodology (https://atomicdesign.bradfrost.com/chapter-2/) to develop these components.

I want to implement stories (with Storybook) or another similar library to document and put examples of each web component.

My question is... Is it possible? I try to install Storybook in the project and isn't working. The question is simple, whether or not you can. And if not, if you know any alternative to it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Storybook, you will need to follow the provided Storybook documentation for lightning "Web Component" rather than the other available options like React and configure your VS Code to work with your SF Environment.  Also, you might want to look into downloading the lwc-services, lwc-webpack-plugin and mo-dx-plugin dependency.